# Fetch 1 to 7 and 7-10 records

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How to retrieve 7-10 record in sql server 2008
in tbl I  have 10 records in that i want only from 7th record to 10th record in sql

I've used

`select * from tbl limit(7,10)`

but this not valid in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**MS SQL 2005+**

```
SELECT Column1,Column2,..
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (Select NULL)) AS RowNum,Column1,Column2,..
    FROM MyTable
) AS Tmp
WHERE Tmp.RowNum BETWEEN 7 AND 10
```

**MS SQL 2012**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ColumnName OFFSET 7 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

**[OFFSET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)**